# Create PDF from specific div

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, mpdf

Good afternoon!

I need to generate a PDF from a HTML page, but from a specific div

```
<div id="canvas">
   all content is here
</div>
```

I have this function as a plugin in CodeIgniter, using mPDF

```
function pdf($html, $filename=null)
{
    require_once("mpdf_lib/mpdf.php");

    $mpdf = new mPDF();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

    if($filename == null){
        $filename = date("Y-m-d").'_test.pdf';
    }

    $mpdf->Output($filename, 'I');
}
```

I just need to know how I can get the html content from that specific div to pass as a parameter in `pdf ($html)` function.

I found many examples but pratically all of them use 'static' html code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all, it's around midnight here! 2ndly, this specific div of yours, where is it? it's in another file in server? is it php generated html?...

Comment: Good evening then!haha This div is in a view (newproject.php) loaded from a controller (codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your php function is located in a codeigniter controller, so that accessing the web page /controllername/pdf calls that function.

Then, use javascript to POST the div's contents to your server. If you are using jquery, see jquery.post. This will invoke the controller function via ajax, and produce the pdf.

```
$.post('/controller/php', {html: $("#canvas").html()})
```

Then change the php function to gather its argument via `$this->input->post('html');`

```
function pdf()
{
    require_once("mpdf_lib/mpdf.php");

    $html = $this->input->post('html');
    $mpdf = new mPDF();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

    $filename = date("Y-m-d").'_test.pdf';

    $mpdf->Output($filename, 'I');
}
```

Comment: The function is found properly. I need to know how to POST the div's content. I don't know much of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a clean way but it works

example i have my html layout in 'views/test'

this is inside `views/test.php`

```
<!--
   Check if $print variable is set
   if it is set then the request is for printing if not the request is for veiwing
-->
<?if(isset($print)):?>

     <!--
       if canvas is set a specific part of the html is only selected
       i did not put an else condition you can supply it if you want
     -->
     <?if($isset($canvas)):?>
           <?if($canvas == 'canvas'):?>
               <div id="canvas">
                  <!--content-->
               </div>

           <?elseif($canvas == 'canvas_two'):?>
               <div id="canvas_two">
                  <!--content-->
              </div>
           <?elseif($canvas == 'canvas_three'):?>
               <div id="canvas_three">
                  <!--content-->
               </div>
           <?endif;?>
     <?endif;?>
<?else:?>
 <div id="canvas">
      <!--content-->
  </div>

 <div id="canvas_two">
      <!--content-->
  </div>

<div id="canvas_three">
      <!--content-->
  </div>
<?endif;?>
```

And on you're controller:

```
function pdf()
{
    require_once("mpdf_lib/mpdf.php");
    //gives of the variable print and canvas on what id
    $html = $this->load->view('test',array('print'=>TRUE,'canvas'=>'canvas'),TRUE);
    $mpdf = new mPDF();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

    if($filename == null){
        $filename = date("Y-m-d").'_test.pdf';
    }

    $mpdf->Output($filename, 'I');
}
```